# How do I setup uicollectionviewcells properly?

Tags: ios, swift, cocoa-touch, uicollectionview, nsattributedstring

I have uicollectionview as chat view and uicollectionviewcell is chat message. Some messages have link and my collectionView(_:cellForItemAt:) calls setupCell(cell:message:) function

```
fileprivate func setupCell(cell: ChatMessageCell, message: RequestMessage) {

var attributedString = NSMutableAttributedString()

if let url = message.url {

    attributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: message.messageText, attributes:[NSAttributedStringKey.link: url, NSAttributedStringKey.font: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 16)])
    cell.textView.attributedText = attributedString
    cell.textView.delegate = self
}

}
```

Problem is when I scroll fast other cells also become links.

[What I want after feral scrolling](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QbFpr.png)

[What I have](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iQMuK.png)

Answer (score 0):

Please write some thing in else part. 
Like :

```
 if let url = message.url {

    attributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: message.messageText, attributes:[NSAttributedStringKey.link: url, NSAttributedStringKey.font: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 16)])
    cell.textView.attributedText = attributedString
    cell.textView.delegate = self
} else {
   //Some code
}
```

Hope It will helps you. Thank you.

Comment: I've tried add this `attributedString.removeAttribute(.link, range: NSMakeRange(0, attributedString.length))`, but doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

Set UITextView's text Property if it is not a link.

```
fileprivate func setupCell(cell: ChatMessageCell, message: RequestMessage) {

cell.textView.attributedText = nil
var attributedString = NSMutableAttributedString()

if let url = message.url {

    attributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: message.messageText, attributes:[NSAttributedStringKey.link: url, NSAttributedStringKey.font: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 16)])
    cell.textView.attributedText = attributedString
    cell.textView.delegate = self
}
else{
    cell.textView.text = message.messageText
    cell.textView.delegate = self
    }
```

Comment: Attribute still moves to other cells

Comment: Did you try setting attributed text to nil when it is not a link?

Comment: Close) If I make (only) .attributedText = nil my messages without link are empty. But when I added .text I got same problem - attribute is everywhere. Hm, how set text properly...

Comment: Set attributedText to nil at the beginning of the function.

Comment: Doesn't work, but I did this `else { cell.textView.attributedText = NSMutableAttributedString(string: message.messageText, attributes:[NSAttributedStringKey.font: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 16)]) }`. Without link) Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

Attribute's problem was solved by setting same attribute without link field. If you know cleaner decision, please write it.

```
var attributedString = NSMutableAttributedString()

if let url = message.url {

attributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: message.messageText, attributes:[NSAttributedStringKey.link: url, NSAttributedStringKey.font: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 16)])
cell.textView.attributedText = attributedString
cell.textView.delegate = self
} else {
cell.textView.attributedText = NSMutableAttributedString(string: message.messageText, attributes:[NSAttributedStringKey.font: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 16)])
}
```